# Update table using random of multiple values in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, sql-server-2012

Consider this data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (DataID INT, Code VARCHAR(2), Prefix VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO #Data (DataID, Code)
VALUES (1, 'AA')
, (2, 'AA')
, (3, 'AA')
, (4, 'AA')
, (5, 'AA')
, (6, 'AA')

CREATE TABLE #Prefix (Code VARCHAR(2), Prefix VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO #Prefix (Code, Prefix)
VALUES ('AA', 'ABC')
, ('AA', 'DEF')
, ('AA', 'GHI')
, ('AA', 'JKL')
```

I want to set the `Prefix` value in `#Data` to be a random `Prefix` from `#Prefix` with a matching `Code`.

Using a straight `inner join` just results in one value being used:

```
UPDATE D
SET Prefix = P.Prefix
FROM #Data AS D
INNER JOIN #Prefix AS P ON D.Code = P.Code
```

From reading other questions on here, `NEWID()` is recommended as a way of randomly ordering something. Changing the `join` to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 subquery ordering by NEWID()
```

still only selects a single value (though random each time) for every row:

```
UPDATE D
SET Prefix = (SELECT TOP 1 P.Prefix FROM #Prefix AS P WHERE P.Code = D.Code ORDER BY NEWID())
FROM #Data AS D
```

So, I'm not sure how to get a random prefix for each data entry from a single update statement. I could probably do some kind of loop through the `#Data` table, but I avoid ever touching loops in `SQL` and I'm sure that would be slow. The actual application of this will be on tens of thousands of records, with hundreds of prefixes for dozens of codes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
UPDATE d SET Prefix = ca.Prefix
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Prefix 
            FROM #Prefix p 
            WHERE d.DataID = d.DataID AND p.Code = d.Code ORDER BY NEWID()) ca
```

Notice `d.DataID = d.DataID`. This is here to force `Sql Server` engine to reevaluate subquery for each row in `#Data` table.

Comment: works great but oh so brittle. use `p.Somecolumn = p.Somecolumn` instead of the outer reference `d.Somecolumn = d.Somecolumns` and it stops working. have some software engineer at MS come up with the innovation of optimizing away conditions that are constant true, and it will stop working.